# a script to set all products in the Confections category that have more than 50 units in stock to a price of $10, and disable them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update, subquery, northwind

I am trying to write a script to set all products in the Confections category that have more than 50 units in stock to a price of $10, and disable them. But I have to include a subquery to identify the category ID from the Category name Confetions. I am also suppose to show before and after that's why I have to select statements. I am lost, here is what I have and I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
I am using sql 2012

```
USE Northwind
SELECT *  
FROM Products
WHERE UnitsInstock > 50 AND CategoryID = 3

UPDATE Products
SET Unitsinstock > 50 
     UnitPrice = 10.00

SELECT *  
FROM Products
WHERE UnitsInstock > 50 AND CategoryID = 3
```

Comment: What is the schema of your Products table? What field and assigned value would disable the products?

Answer (score 1):

Your second query looks incorrect. I think you need to add a WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE Products
SET UnitPrice = 10.00
WHERE Unitsinstock > 50 AND CategoryID = 3
```